# ASP.NET - drop down list

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i have 2 tables in my database:

```
Employee  (ID , NAME , SALARY , departmentNo)
```

ID is primary key and departmentNo foreign key from Department.ID

```
Department (ID , Name , Location)
```

ID is primary key

So I want to make drop down list that shows on a form names of departments, and when user press "add" button it should save departmentNo on table.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution of your question. I have used some extra variables just to check values are coming or not you can replace them as per your need.

```
 db_connection();
        string id=null;
        string h = comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
        string select = "select ID from Department where Name='" + h + "'";
        SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand(select,Cn);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            id = dr[0].ToString();
        }
        dr.Close();
        select = "insert into Employee (NAME,SALARY,departmentNo)values(@NAME,@SALARY,@departmentNo)";
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(select, Cn);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAME", textBox1.Text);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SALARY", textBox2.Text);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@departmentNo", id);
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: you seem to have forgotten the bit where the question says "I want to make drop down list that shows on a form". Also the first query randomly doesn't use parameters when it should, and thus is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. It's also not clear why this first query even accepts a parameter - the first goal is to make a dropdown of all departments

Comment: @ADyson i dont understand one thing if someone knows a better answer for this question then they should provide the answer to the question rather than giving such suggestions and comments.

Comment: or you could use the suggestion to improve your answer and get more upvotes. Personally I'd voted to close the question as too broad since it's asking for quite a lot, hence I didn't answer it myself. But I checked back on things in my recent history and since you answered, and the answer could be improved I thought I'd make a suggestion. If you don't want to improve the answer, that is if course your choice.